# PySide6.Qt- namespace won't show suggestions in VSC -

Tags: python-3.x, qt, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pyside6

This might be a dumb problem but it's driving me nuts..
Hopefully an experienced VSC user can help me out here.

I am working with PySide in VSC and, since I'm starting, relying on the Intellisense suggestions is helpfull to get my coding right.
the problem is that Qt flags never show up when I start typing ... It is properly imported and applied, but I can't be sure its ok until I run the code.

enviroment vars are set properly and path is stablished for python // python scripts // pyside .

Is there any way to "edit" the suggestions made by intellisense??
Has anyone been through this problem and solve ??

[Intellisense working accordingly with class QStatusBar()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCQtF.jpg)
[Qt lib recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRUOD.jpg)
[Qt flag "AlignCenter" not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4DsM.jpg)

Tried reinstalling PySide, VSC, different extensions, nothing worked

Comment: In a move that follow what more rigidly introduced in PyQt6, PySide6 is gradually introducing *actual* [python enums](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html#the-new-python-enums), which require their full namespace as PyQt6. Long story short: in the meantime you can still use the "old" basic naming (without the namespace of the class the enum belongs to), but you won't get suggestions as they are not considered standard anymore, and their support will probably be removed sooner or later.